# Is there any way to make my svelte web app to run locally on iOS?

Tags: node.js, cordova, flutter, web-applications, svelte

I have developed an app using svelte and have uploaded it to a server. Since it contains private information, I cannot share the domain with other people. So basically, the web app should be private.

But if I want to make other people use my webapp, how can I do that? 
In a PC, I can give them the source code and make them locally build their webapp on their localhost:3000 using npm-run dev.

How can I achieve this on a mobile device like Android or iOS?

Comment: You can serve the app in another computer connected to the same LAN and access it with the phone. (Normally you need to change the bind IP adress for the web server.)

Comment: That could be one solution but I want to make it easily distributable. Is there any tools that converts it to a cordova app or flutter?

Comment: You can run cordova with its nodejs plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-mobile-cordova Making it run svelte's build before running.

Comment: Hagai Wild, Can you be a little more specific? I'm new to this era..

Answer (score 0):

You can use now.sh a.k.a. ZEIT / Vercel. Deploying your Github files is very easy.

https://vercel.com/guides/deploying-svelte-with-vercel?query=svelte

You can use this hosting for free with limitation of course.